# Retrieving value of controls added dynamically from $.ajax callback

Tags: ajax, user-controls, jquery

I am making a master/details style grid with Ajax and JQuery.
In the main grid, you have a one-liner with basic info and a + to click and when you click the +, the row is expended with the details fetched using the JSON technic with JQuery.
The example i used to get this working can be found [here](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/GridView-Grouping-Master-Detail-Drill-Down-Using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)
A user control is created and generates html that is pasted in a div from the original page.

The diffrence is that on the details section, instead of having a line number, i have a html input checkbox (as an asp checkbox requires a form to work) with the runat=server tag and the value set to the id of the item it represent.

My question is that how can I get if the checkbox is checked or not (or values from any other controls) in code-behind?

Comment: the example link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can try using hidden checkboxes which correspond to the actual ones, so when the form is submitted the checked values will be sent.